# which process shouldn't be running , need to Identify it to grab the associated file , what to do ?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I am kinda stuck and need help in some task here in which I need to first just "identify" which process shouldn't be running and after grabbing that process I need to list the files associated to it and kill it.

Now I need help only in the identification of that process , I have been trying to trace that but I am not able to identify , I would sincerely appreciate any help ..!!

Attached Image is the list of processes ..!!

OS : Debian OS

[list of processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8zQ3.png)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean with "a process that should not be running"? We don't know what you are doing with your machine, its settings, etc. -- there's no way for someone to know which process should not be running in such context.

Comment: @JamilSaid Thanks for your reply , I need to search for a running process that shouldn't be there and check the files opened by it , ideally I can list all the files opened by all the processes but that too comes out to be a whole list , the end goal is to identify the file which has been opened by a process where I have to grab the file content. hope it helps ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the answer , among the list of processes the yum process shouldn't be running on Debian OS , as well as post listing all the files associated with that process , I was able to grab the files that I can edit.

`lsof -p <pid>`

```
lsof -a -d^txt
```